# Technical Debt Pyramid Widget in Sonarqube 5.5?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

as we all know, the Technical Debt Pyramid Widget was moved into SonarQube core in version 4.0. 
But now in Sonarqube5.5, I'm not able to find it? Is it still exists? Is it plan to be introduced in Sonarqube 5.x one day?

Thanx !

Answer (score 1):

The Technical Debt Pyramid is removed in 5.5, which introduces an updated quality model. Before that it should be available. There are no plans to bring it back.

Comment: Sorry, I use sonarqube 5.5. I didn't see any debt pyramid inside ?